# Create picture of flash application hosted by ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

How can I programatically make a picture of a flash application in an ASP.NET/C# page which is hosting the flash application? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

[website screenshot component](http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/Usage.html)

Comment: ok, but flash doesn't take all screen, only some part. And i really like to take a picture only of flash application. And it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this post: [Extract Bitmap or BitmapData from MovieClip](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?266493-Extract-Bitmap-or-BitmapData-from-MovieClip)

You could use something like this:

```
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(something, orrather)
myBitmapData.draw(theNameOfTheMovieClipThatYouNeedAsABitmap);
```

Then you can try to follow [the suggestions on this post to upload your BitmapData to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762226/501196).